# MongoDB 'Active' Count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a query that i am trying to use to get an 'active' count of objects i.e. a count of objects that have not been deleted.  My query works but only if no object has been deleted. For example the query returns a count of 5 chairs, 3 tables, 7 rugs etc.  I'd like the query to be adjusted so that if say 2 chairs & 1 rug is deleted in the app, the new return count would be 3 chairs, 3 tables & 6 rugs. Right now of course, it's still showing 5 chairs, 3 tables & 7 rugs.  Basically looking for a MongoDB version of 'where deleted is null'.  I realize there's a difference between RDS and NoSQL but is there a way to adjust the query to get that same result? Below is my query, thanks!

```
db.getCollection("events").aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match": {
                "caseid":"0gke34",
                "field.type" : {"$ne" : null}
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$group" : {
                "id" : "field.type", "TotalCount": { $sum: 1 }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Provide the data model you are using. And how the deleted records are mapped in the database.

Comment: _"... deleted in the app ..."_ Are they also deleted in the collection?

Comment: @rickhg12hs great question and no, they are not deleted in the collection.  simply a 'delete' record is inserted. so if there was 1 'create' record in the collection, now there's 1 'create' record and 1 'delete' record.  I'd like to ignore any creates that have associated deletes.

Comment: With _"create"_ and _"delete"_ records (documents?), I don't think you can ignore anything - you'll need to account for all of them.  Perhaps if you show some example documents in the collection, a working aggregation pipeline could be offered.

Comment: @rickhg12hs  Yes, sorry documents :) i work in RDS mainly so just used to records. So my thought isn't so much to 'ignore' as much as creating an 'if' statement so to speak. Like every group of related docs share a common id, so like is there a way to say 'ignore' i.e. don't include in the total, any ids that have a create AND delete document? Something like that? I realize I'm thinking with a heavy RDS mindset as that's the world i live in & this is BEYOND easy there.I realize its not so simple in NoSQL. Guess i was just hoping some smart person could think of a way to accomplish it anyway :)

Comment: @rickhg12hs i just had a idea. Create 2 line counts, 1 each for creates & deletes. Example, chairs has 5 create & 4 delete docs, table has 3 creates & 2 deletes, rugs has 7 create & 2 delete docs etc. I can simply do the math from there.  So the output would be something like:  chair: create: 5,  chair delete: 4, talbes: create: 3 tables: delete: 2, rugs create: 7 rugs delete: 2.   It'd be SUPER easy to just mentally math my way to the 'active' count.   Any easy way to edit the query to separate the create / delete counts for each object?

Comment: In `"$group"`, you could conditionally add or subtract depending on status of _create_ or _delete_.  If you show some example documents, an aggregation pipeline could be made to provide the output you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254016/discussion-between-sean-and-rickhg12hs).